# PHP ZipArchive Not Working in Laravel

Tags: php

PHP ZipArchive is working perfectly if I run it in raw php, but getting a "class not found" error when I try to run it in my Laravel project:

> FatalErrorException in WidgetController.php line 40:
>   Class 'App\Http\Controllers\ZipArchive' not found

Here's the function I have in my laravel controller:

```
public function installHello()
{
    $file_path = base_path("resources/assets/packages/helloworld.zip");

    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    if ($zip->open($file_path) === TRUE) {
        $zip->extractTo(base_path('packages/tkabir/'));
        $zip->close();
        return redirect()->back();
        //echo 'ok';
    } else {
        echo 'failed';
    }
}
```

And here's the sample I tried in an index.php file:

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('E:/xampp/htdocs/ziptest/helloworld.zip') === TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo('E:/xampp/htdocs/ziptest/');
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
?>
```

Any idea why it wouldn't work in laravel?

Comment: well class not found means exactly that

Comment: call a Class like this : `$zip = new ZipArchive();`

Answer (score 18):

Problem solved. Made an obvious mistake: forgot to ''use ZipArchive'' in my Laravel controller

Answer (score 6):

Add `use ZipArchive;` in your controller, this work for me.

Comment: I use this and phpstorm editor show me the next steps... (i put that steps in new answer, thanks!!!)

Answer (score 0):

On composer.json add line:

```
"require": {
  [...]     
  "ext-zip": "*"  /* this line */ 
},
```

Execute:

```
composer update
```

On your controller use this lines:

```
use ZipArchive;
[...]

// use this form to instance the object 
$zip = new \ZipArchive();
```